# using an Array formula to do VLOOKUP in multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I have used below formula in [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r791h8xoopgtfoh/Test%20Array-%202.xls?dl=0) but I do not know why it doesn not work and return #N/A!? Infact I need to lookup "Station .No" from other sheets to display it in Sheet1  :

```
= VLOOKUP(I3,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetList,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!$A$5:$N$500"),I3)>0),0))&"'!$A$5:$N$500"),14,FALSE)
```

Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem isn't with multiple sheets; it's with the way you are using `VLOOKUP`. This function matches values the left-most column in its array argument and then you can offset that using your 14 at the end. In your case, the `FOP No.` matches appear in column B, so you need to start your array there. Changing A -> B and 14 -> 13 works for most of the cases.

```
=VLOOKUP(I3,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetList,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!$B$5:$N$500"),I3)>0),0))&"'!$B$5:$N$500"),13,FALSE)
```

Some of your values will still turn up `#N/A` with this since the cells you are matching have trailing spaces (e.g. `"A1-CHASSIS-500  "` instead of `"A1-CHASSIS-500"`), but that's another matter. (Hint: `TRIM()` removes extra spaces.)